# Is there any docs about the principle of IK provided by KDL?

Tags: ros, ik, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

recently i'm using the inverse kinematics(IK) service provided by KDL. it works great! but i want to know its principles. is there any docs, papers about this?

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48431/is-there-any-docs-about-the-principle-of-ik-provided-by-kdl?/) by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 741 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on which solver you're talking about.

Of the solvers listed [here](http://people.mech.kuleuven.be/%7Ersmits/kdl/api/html/annotated.html), there are "IK velocity" solvers and "IK position" solvers. There's only really one type of "position" solver listed (with variants that do and do not enforce joint limits). This is the [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) solver (`ChainIKSolverPos_NR_*`). This is an iterative solver which requires a way to compute the gradient of the jacobian at each iteration. This gradient is computed by one of the several "velocity" solvers (`ChainIKSolverVel_*`) and each solver computes this gradient in a different way. You can see how the Newton-Raphson "position solver" calls the "velocity solver" [here](https://github.com/jbohren-forks/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/blob/master/orocos_kdl/src/chainiksolverpos_nr.cpp#L41) (I'm linking to a fork of mine for the sake of syntax hilighting via github).

Not listed there, however, is the [Levenberg-Marquardt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) solver (`ChainIKSolverPos_LMA`), the source of which can be seen [here (header)](https://github.com/jbohren-forks/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/blob/master/orocos_kdl/src/chainiksolverpos_lma.hpp) and [here (source)](https://github.com/jbohren-forks/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/blob/master/orocos_kdl/src/chainiksolverpos_lma.cpp).

This primer gives a pretty good overview of some of these methods: [http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/ikmethods/iksurvey.pdf](http://math.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/ResearchWeb/ikmethods/iksurvey.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-11-15**:
thanks man. i will take a look at these.